# Analytic structures on $S^1$|

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, analyticity, real-algebraic-geometry, foliations

I am currently studying Haefliger's paper "Homotopy and Integrablity". During the last chapter, he applies his theory of $\Gamma$-structures to analytic codimension $1$ foliations.

Throughout the argument he asserts "two analytic structures on $S^1$ are analytically isomorphic". I can imagine this is the case, just as there is a single holomorphic/analyitic (complex) structure on $S^2$; however, in my head, this is a consequence of the uniformization theorem... so I haven't been able to work out an analogous proof to the $1$-dimensional real analytic case.

My question is: Is this an obvious fact?

If so, where do I start?
If NOT, is there any reference where I can look it up?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to use the definition of an analytic structure to construct a real-analytic parametrization of the circle, then lift this to a strictly monotone real-analytic function $\phi$ on the reals. If that succeeds, "it's obvious": If $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$ are analytic and strictly monotone, so is $\phi_{1} \circ \phi_{2}^{-1}$.